# How do I check if a letter is bold?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change all bold characters to italic ones and vica versa. I figured out I need to iterate through the entire document.

So far I defined the two styles and a part of the function, not sure if the styles are needed.

```
        .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .italic {
            font-style: italic;
        }

        <script>
        function swap() {
            if (fontWeight == 'bold') {
                fontWeight == 'normal';
                fontStyle == 'italic';
            }
            elseif (fontStyle == 'italic') {
                fontStyle == 'normal';
                fontWeight == 'bold';
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Where's the code that iterates through the entire document? Does each element in the document have one of the `bold` or `italic` classes?

Comment: Seems a little odd, but have you considered adding `<style disabled>.bold {font-weight: normal; font-style: italic;} .italic {font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;}</style>` and then toggling the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: you could define css classes ('.bold', '.italic') and use jQuery to select based on classes and then use add/remove class

Comment: You can use the hasClass() method to check if the element has the class associated, and then use the addClass() or removeClass().

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this with `querySelectorAll`, considering only swapping `.bold` and `.italic` depending on their current class:

```js
function swapCollection( collection, from, to ) {
  if ( !collection ) {
    return;
  }
  
  for( let i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i ) {
    const elm = collection[ i ];
    elm.classList.remove( from );
    elm.classList.add( to );
  }
}

function swap() {
  const allBold = document.querySelectorAll( '.bold' );
  const allItalic = document.querySelectorAll( '.italic' );
  
  swapCollection( allBold, 'bold', 'italic' );
  swapCollection( allItalic, 'italic', 'bold' );
}

document.getElementById( 'swap' ).addEventListener( 'click', swap );
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="bold">Hello</span> <span class="italic">world!</span>
</div>

<button id="swap">swap</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use getElementsByClassName to choose class and change style then:

```
   function swap() {
    var mass=document.getElementsByClassName("bold");
      for (i in mass){
        mass[i].style.fontWeight="normal";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not useful to add a JS script for something that can be done once and for all.
so try to overwrite the default style of strong and em tags inyour CSS files by adding the following CSS code

```
strong, b{ font-weight: normal!important; font-style: italic!important;  }
em, i{font-style: normal!important; font-weight: bold!important; }
```

then replace all properties in your CSS files

```
font-style: italic; by font-weight: bold;
```

and

```
font-weight: bold; by font-style: italic;
```

using your IDE

Comment: You should never use `!important`, because this will result into hard to maintain css code, especially not for general selectors like `strong`, `b`, `em`, `i`, ...  . It should only be used for very specific selectors, and only if there is no other way to solve the problem.

Comment: You're right, I just added them to reinforce the code, but you can remove them and the code still remains functional

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalize solution, using jQuery, not based only on class names.
I do the bolded texts red so you can see it easily.

```js
$('div').each(function () {
  if ($(this).css('font-weight') == 'bold') {
   $(this).css('color', 'red'); // but you change to italic
    return;
  }
  if ($(this).css('font-style') == 'italic') {
   $(this).css('color', 'green'); // but you change to bold
    return;
  }
  
});
```

```css
.one, .three {font-weight: bold;}
.five {font-style: italic;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">aaa</div>
<div>ccc</div>
<div class="three">ddd</div>
<div>eee</div>
<div style="font-weight: bold;">lala</div>
<div style="font-style: italic;">tata</div>
<div>nana</div>
<div class="five">dada</div>
```

If you want to apply something to a text which is both bold and italic, remove the `return`s in the `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply a matter of toggling the classes, you could do it like this. Each time you click the button it will change the bold text to italic and vice versa.

```js
const
  trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
  
function toggleClasses() {
  const
    // Get all the elements with the bold and/or italic class.
    elements = document.querySelectorAll('.bold, .italic');
  
  // Iterate over all the elements
  elements.forEach(element => {
    // For each element, toggle the bold and italic classes.
    element.classList.toggle('bold');
    element.classList.toggle('italic');
  });
}
  
trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleClasses);
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p class="bold">initally bold</p>
<p class="bold">initally bold</p>
<p class="italic">initally italic</p>
<p class="bold">initally bold</p>
<p class="italic">initially italic</p>
<button id="trigger" type="button">toggle classes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply collect all items with `.bold` and `.italic` classes under a node list with `document.querySelectorAll(".bold, .italic")` and [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) their `classList`s.

```js
var sps = document.querySelectorAll(".bold, .italic"),
    mbt = document.getElementById("mbt");
mbt.addEventListener("click", _ => sps.forEach(function(sp){
                                                 sp.classList.toggle("bold");
                                                 sp.classList.toggle("italic");
                                               }));
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="bold">Hello</span> <span class="italic">World</span></p>
<button id="mbt">Toggle</button>
```